# Startup script for two screens and one computer

Tags: windows-7, script, boot

I have a situation where I have two screens attached to one windows computer and I have to trigger 2 different applications on 2 different screens on start-up.

What I think that I will need some kind of batch script in startup to do this, but still not sure how this will be achieved. Any code / example / application suggestion will be a great help.

**EDIT:** The problem is that applications do not remember which screen to go to.

Comment: Which version of Windows?

Comment: Is the issue that the applications do not remember their window position?

Comment: I"d look at autoit. You can start applications and move them to the appropriate monitor based on screen coordinates. It would be a relatively simple script.